# JavaSE Adding Object in list but object changes Why?

Tags: java

i was trying to add shape object's current position into my arraylist but when the object position change my list objects change too..

searching after many hours later i found a different way and now position stay same even the object position change

here my first code that cause change in arraylist:

```
    MyPoint p11 = (MyPoint) getCorners()[0];
    MyPoint p22 = (MyPoint) getCorners()[1];
    MyPoint p33 = (MyPoint) getCorners()[2];
    MyPoint p44 = (MyPoint) getCorners()[3];
```

here is the second code that never change the object position

```
    MyPoint p11 = new MyPoint(getCorners()[0].getX(), getCorners()[0].getY());
    MyPoint p22 = new MyPoint(getCorners()[1].getX(), getCorners()[1].getY());
    MyPoint p33 = new MyPoint(getCorners()[2].getX(), getCorners()[2].getY());
    MyPoint p44 = new MyPoint(getCorners()[3].getX(), getCorners()[3].getY());
```

when i use the below code i was monitoring output and with first code they change , with second they dont

```
        System.out.println(nl.get(0).getCorners()[0].getX());
        System.out.println(nl.get(0).getCorners()[1].getX());
        System.out.println(nl.get(0).getCorners()[2].getX());
        System.out.println(nl.get(0).getCorners()[3].getX());
```

My question is that i want to know and learn the difference between two 
code.

Could you please explain to me guys..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In one you create a new object and change it (the one with `new` in it). In the other you're referencing an object that's in the list.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing `MyPoint p11 = (MyPoint) getCorners()[0];` you still referring the existing not creating new one which means any modification in existing object will reflect in p11

but with  `MyPoint p11 = new MyPoint(getCorners()[0].getX(), getCorners()[0].getY());` you are creating new object.  So any modification in existing object will not reflect in p11

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the first variant you put into the list objects that you later change, in the second you you create copies of those objects, so when the original objects change, the copies remain unchanged.

I'd suggest that you refactor the class `MyPoint` so that is will be immutable. That means that the values `x` and `y` will be final and there will be no method `setX`, `setY` (you would initialize the values `x` and `y` in the constructor).

When you then move the shape, instead of changing the values of `x` and `y` you exchange the whole points.

This will allow you to reuse the same points in multiple shapes, you will be able to put the points into lists etc. without worrying about them being later changed by some unrelated code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this happened with you because in the code that you've written first you get a reference to the object inside the array list and assigning that to a new object say p11, however this new object still points to the existing one (it is a reference to the one that's already in the arraylist), so whatever changes you make on p11 they'll be reflected in the object in the list, because basically they are the same thing. In the second case, you are creating a new instance of the class using the values of the object in the array list (by passing them inside the constructor). The object you've defined is a new instance and it is completely different from those in the list, so whatever change you make on it, the corresponding object in the list won't change.